# How do I solve this multiplication problem?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

I am trying to answer this puzzle my friend created and sent to me - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

> $ 10 \times 5 = 60 \\  
> 6 \times 12 = 72 \\  
> 8 \times 3 = 44 \\  
> 5 \times 9 =\,? $

Possible answers:

> A) 54
>   B) 56
>   C) 58
>   D) 60
>   E) 62

Comment: Hi! You need to include a source if you post a puzzle you didn't create. Also note that you can't include a question that is part of an ongoing competition. Thanks and happy puzzling!

Comment: My friend created this puzzle ant sent to me.

Comment: I added the above information into the original post. I hope that helps, and welcome to PSE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> B)56

because:

> if "a*b=c" then c=4(a+b)